# How to rewrite call using apply?

Tags: javascript

This was the problem statement:

> Imagine JavaScript didn't natively include the call function. The apply function however still exists.
>
> Using apply, write call.
>
> Note: console.log internally uses the 'call' function, which therefore means you can't debug using console.log as it will either call an empty function or cause an infinite loop.

This is my attempt (which isn't working):

```
Function.prototype.call = function(a) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[1]);
  Function.prototype.apply(a, args);
}
```

Second attempt:

```
Function.prototype.call = function(a) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[1]);
  this.apply(a, args);
  console.log("OKAY!");
}

var person1 = {name: 'Marvin', age: 42, size: '2xM'};
var person2 = {name: 'Zaphod', age: 42000000000, size: '1xS'};

var sayHello = function(){
    alert('Hello, ' + this.name);
};

var sayGoodbye = function(){
    alert('Goodbye, ' + this.name);
};

sayGoodbye.call(person2);
```

This seems to check out in JSFiddle, but not on the platform I'm solving the problem on (codewars.com)

EDIT: Thanks. I tried the same without using return and the code did not pass. However, the behavior seems the same. What is the difference if I return or don't return? I thought my attempt would be correct because call is supposed to call the function that is accessing call, right? In that case, returning the result of calling the function seems a bit strange to me.

But here's me trying to reason it out: if I use the default call with foo.call(a), I am calling foo with a as this, with all return behavior being the same as foo's. In my second attempt, we call this.apply, so that we can use the calling function. Function.prototype.apply in my original attempt has no idea who called apply. But if all we do is call apply, without returning, then if the original function (this) has a return value, we won't get it back and the behavior would be different from the default call's behavior. Is this right?

Comment: You're not far off... don't cheat yourself out of the learning opportunity that solving this problem on your own would afford you.

Comment: my hint: first write a "regular" call function and once you get that to work  then try adding the a call method to Function.prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function.prototype.call = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[1]);
  return this.apply(arguments[0], args);
};
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I did something similar in my second attempt. I wrote up some thoughts on that, can you please confirm if they are correct?